# Javascript error console in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I know how to do it in Firefox - how do I see Javascript errors in Chrome?

Answer (score 9):

You have following options:

- Chrome: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Mac) and it will give similar functionality. Also consider checking out JavaScript debugger in Chrome. Hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> works as well.
- IE7: Nothing built in. But have a look at [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).
- IE8: Just hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and you will get access to some very capable built-in tools. Error console is on Script tab.
- Firefox: Just use [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com).
- Opera: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac) to launch Opera Drangonfly which is a fully featured development and debugging tool integrated into the Opera browser.
- Safari: Enable the Developer Menu from Safari's preferences. It will give access the various tools (Error Console, Web Inspector, JavaScript Profiler, etc). Of course there are also shortcuts, like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for the console.

Comment: Please do not include irrelevant links in posts, especially if you are directly affiliated with the website being linked. All self-promotion must correspond to the rules outlined in the [FAQ#promotion].

Answer (score 7):

found it myself: developer tools, then there's a symbol at the bottom left "show console"

Comment: For other options, see http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/ and http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html (though written for Safari, many things are based on WebKit).

Comment: i will as soon as i can... "you can accept your own answer in 2 days" so this is a chance for easy points: post my answer yourself and I'll accept you. :D

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this (or Millhouse's answer) as otherwise the question will keep popping up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Any of these:

- Hit F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I
- right-click on any element on the page, and "Inspect Element"
- Wrench button -> Tools -> Developer Tools

Then go to Console tab

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you are viewing are a page, right-click, select 'Inspect element'

This opens Developer tools in html inspector mode - select 'console' and you can view errors by clicking 'errors' at the bottom